# CoreData - NSManagedObject SubObject Only Stored in one Object at a time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have two CoreData Entities: `List` and `Item`. `List` contains a relationship with a destination of `Item`. It is a to-many relationship (`List` entities can contain many `Item`s)

```
List = {
  id: String,
  name: String
  items: <Item>
}

Item = {
  id: String,
  name: String
}
```

Now, let's say we have: 
2 total Lists -> `List_1` and `List_2` 
3 total Items: `Item_1`, `Item_2`, and `Item_3`.

The lists looks like:

```
List_1 = {
  id: "1001",
  name: "Foo"
  items: <Item_1, Item_2>
}

List_2 = {
  id: "1002",
  name: "Bar"
  items: <Item_2, Item_3>
}
```

When I make a fetch against CoreData I am experiencing inconsistent results, and the inconsistency is based on the last `List` that was loaded in the app.

For example, if I use the app and the last list I load is `List_1` when I query to get all the items in `List_1` I am returned:

`Item_1`, `Item_2`

HOWEVER, if I use the app and the last list I load is `List_2` when I query to get all the items in `List_1` I am returned:

`Item_1` (only....NO `Item_2`?!) as if it was "moved" out of `List_1` and into `List_2` since `List_2` is the last list that was visited that contained `Item_2.

Are CoreData objects that are stored as part of a one-to-many relationship only allowed to exist in one CoreData object at a time? Does anybody see something wrong with how I am approaching this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a one to many relationship between List and items:

```
List <-->>Items
```

[image: One to Many]

that mean one list can have many items but one item can have just one list.

But you want the items to be able to belong to many lists, so you need to create a many to many relationship between list and items

```
List <<-->>Items
```

In this case one list can have many Items but one Item can belong to many lists.

[image: Many to Many]

I hope that helps

Comment: You are awesome! This is exactly what the issue was. Thank you for the crystal clear explanation!

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help, was kind challenging put this into words so I am happy that you got it. Good luck with your app!